# I am implementing a doubly linked list in C, and having segmentation fault in a destroy function

Tags: c, gcc, command-line, compilation, segmentation-fault

I divided the code in two files, .h and .c
The definition of function names is in .h, the implementation of the function is in .c

in my main file:

```
struct no
{        
    tipo info;      
    struct no *ant; 
    struct no *nxt;
};
struct list    
{
    no_t *head; 
    no_t *tail; 
    int size;
};
```

this is in my .h file:

```
typedef     struct no       no_t;
typedef     struct list     list_t;
typedef     int             tipo;
```

...again in main

```
void list_destroy(list_t **l)
{
    if ((*l) == NULL || l == NULL)
        return;
    if (!(*l)->head)
        return;

    no_t *next = (*l)->head;       //create two variables for iterating through the list
    no_t *aux;                     //set aux to free

    while (next->nxt)             //the pointer for next node, in the last node, is NULL
    {                             //by that I believe I'm able to iterate through all nodes
        aux = next;
        free(aux);
        next = next->nxt;
    }

    free(*l);
    (*l) = NULL;
}
```

is quite a simple code, but I can't see where I'm missing here

Comment: I'm not sure if the cause of the crash in your `list_destroy` function, but you have a memory leak.  Consider the case where you only have a single node in the list. It won't get free'd.  But, chances are high your crash is caused by corruption somewhere else. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  next = next->nxt;
```

For the compiler it makes no difference, for sure.  But for someone, even you, it is hard to read this  `next = next->nxt` stuff. Or is it is not?

### A possible alternative (using your code) and a short test program

#### so_list.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int Tipo;

typedef struct st_no
{
    Tipo            info;
    struct st_no*   prev;
    struct st_no*   next;

}   Node;


typedef struct
{
    Node*       head;
    Node*       tail;
    unsigned    size;

}   List;


List*       list_create();
List*       list_destroy(List*);
int         list_insert(const Tipo, List*);
```

- In the header, only typedefs and the function prototypes.
- names with only the first letter in uppercase are reserved here for defined names. An useful convention.
- instead of using `List**` is often clearer to just return the pointer to the list. In this way it is easier for example to invalidate the pointer and to create the linked lists as in

```
    List* my_list = list_create();
    my_list = list_destroy(my_list);
```

and there is no need to test the two levels of indirection as you need when `**` is used

#### main.c: a minimalist test set

```
#include "so-list.h"

int main(void)
{
    List* my_list = list_create();
    my_list = list_destroy(my_list);

    my_list = list_create();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i += 1)
        printf("insert(%d,list) returned %d\n",
            i, list_insert(i,my_list) 
        );
    my_list = list_destroy(my_list);


    my_list = list_create();
    for (int i = 11; i <= 15; i += 1)
        printf("insert(%d,list) returned %d\n",
            i, list_insert(i, my_list)
        );
    my_list = list_destroy(my_list);
    return 0;
}
```

- A list is created, then destroyed
- using the same pointer, a list is created, values 1 to 5 are inserted ant then the list is deleted.
- using the same pointer, a list is created, values 11 to 15 are inserted ant then the list is again deleted.

#### the output

```
List created!
List deleted!

List created!
insert(1,list) returned 1
insert(2,list) returned 2
insert(3,list) returned 3
insert(4,list) returned 4
insert(5,list) returned 5
1 deleted
2 deleted
3 deleted
4 deleted
5 deleted
List deleted!

List created!
insert(11,list) returned 1
insert(12,list) returned 2
insert(13,list) returned 3
insert(14,list) returned 4
insert(15,list) returned 5
11 deleted
12 deleted
13 deleted
14 deleted
15 deleted
List deleted!
```

#### code for `destroy_list()`

```
List* list_destroy(List* l)
{
    if (l == NULL) return NULL;
    // delete the ´size´ nodes, 1 by 1
    Node* p = NULL;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < l->size; i += 1)
    {
        p = l->head->next; // save pointer
        printf("%d deleted\n", l->head->info); // just for the demo
        free(l->head); // free head
        l->head = p; // advance head
    }
    free(l); // free list
    printf("List deleted!\n\n"); // just for the demo
    return NULL;
}
```

This function always return `NULL` as just a way to invalidade the pointer in the caller in the same expression as in `pList = destroy_list(pList);`

This is somewhat different than the code you wrote. We just delete the elements one by one as we know the list has `size` elements. A local pointer is used in the loop to save the address of the next element. It seems to be easier to read.

### The complete code for so-list.c

```
#include  "so-list.h"

List* list_create()
{
    List* one = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    one->head = NULL;
    one->tail = NULL;
    one->size = 0;
    printf("List created!\n");
    return one;
}


List* list_destroy(List* l)
{
    if (l == NULL) return NULL;
    // delete the ´size´ nodes, 1 by 1
    Node* p = NULL;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < l->size; i += 1)
    {
        p = l->head->next; // save pointer
        printf("%d deleted\n", l->head->info);
        free(l->head); // free head
        l->head = p; // advance head
    }
    free(l); // free list
    printf("List deleted!\n\n");
    return NULL;
}


// just for test, insert ´info´ at the end, returns size
int         list_insert(const Tipo info, List* l)
{
    // insert node at the end, just for test
    Node* one = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    one->info = info;
    one->next = NULL;
    one->prev = l->tail;
    if (l->size == 0)
        l->head = one; // 1st node
    else
        l->tail->next = one;
    l->tail = one;
    l->size += 1;
    return l->size;
};
```

### about your version of list_destroy()

The logic there is a bit wrong but the error is well described in another answer. I recommend not to use `**` in this situations. But it can be done for sure.

### so-list.c

This is just a minimum to have a running test

```
#include  "so-list.h"

List* list_create()
{
    List* one = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    one->head = NULL;
    one->tail = NULL;
    one->size = 0;
    printf("List created!\n");
    return one;
}


List* list_destroy(List* l)
{
    if (l == NULL) return NULL;
    // delete the ´size´ nodes, 1 by 1
    Node* p = NULL;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < l->size; i += 1)
    {
        p = l->head->next; // save pointer
        printf("%d deleted\n", l->head->info);
        free(l->head); // free head
        l->head = p; // advance head
    }
    free(l); // free list
    printf("List deleted!\n\n");
    return NULL;
}


// just for test, insert ´info´ at the end, returns size
int         list_insert(const Tipo info, List* l)
{
    // insert node at the end, just for test
    Node* one = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    one->info = info;
    one->next = NULL;
    one->prev = l->tail;
    if (l->size == 0)
        l->head = one; // 1st node
    else
        l->tail->next = one;
    l->tail = one;
    l->size += 1;
    return l->size;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This has an issue

```
no_t *next = (*l)->head;
no_t *aux;

while (next->nxt)
{
    aux = next;       // aux point to the same object as next
    free(aux);        // free aux, which is the same as next
    next = next->nxt; // deference next, which just got free'd.  OOPS!
}
```

You invoke `free` on aux, which is also aliasing `next`.  Then you try to deference `next->nxt`.  Well, `next` just got released in the previous statement.  Also, as I called out in the comment, you are leaking the last element in the list.

Fixed:

```
no_t* aux = (*l)->head;
while (aux)
{
    no_t* next = aux->nxt;
    free(aux);
    aux = next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look to your "free" and your "next->nxt" statements. May it can help you solve it.